# Java - How to check if BufferedReader contains line break before running readLine command

Tags: java, bufferedreader, readline

I am trying to parse HTML from a website to get very specific data. The following method reads the source and outputs it as a string to be processed by other methods.

```
    StringBuilder source = new StringBuilder();
    URL url = new URL(urlIn);
    URLConnection spoof;
    spoof = url.openConnection();
    spoof.setRequestProperty( "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0; H010818)" );

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(spoof.getInputStream()));
    String strLine = "";

    while ((strLine = in.readLine()) != null){
        source.append(strLine);
    }

    return source.toString();
```

The problem that I'm having is that since I call this method multiple times with a different urlIn argument each time, sometimes the method gets stuck at the readLine command. I read that this is because readLine looks for a line break and if the BufferedReader object does not contain one for whatever reason, it will be stuck indefinitely.

Is there a way to check whether my BufferedReader object contains a line break before I run the readLine command. I tried using an `if (in.toString().contains("\n"))` but that always returns false. Alternatively, could I add a "\n" at the end of my Buffered Reader "in" object every time just so that the while loop would break and not hang up indefinitely?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this here should be what you are looking for.

```
fis = new FileInputStream("C:/sample.txt");
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

System.out.println("Reading File line by line using BufferedReader");

String line = reader.readLine();
while(line != null){
    System.out.println(line);
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/07/read-file-line-by-line-java-example-scanner.html#ixzz3g4RHvy6V

Edit, in your case, since it seems like you are doing webapp testing, I do believe WebDriverWait may work for your needs.

Comment: In essence it appears as though you want it to read a new line. after it is done appending.

Comment: I am trying to return the entire html code through this method. I am sorry but isn't the code you suggested also susceptible to hanging at the readLine() command like my original code is doing? The reason I can't test this immediately and find out is that I am calling this method hundreds of times and it only hangs sometimes and that too randomly.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure to be honest. If your code hangs up try putting some sort of checker inside of it that keeps track of the time and if it exceeds it then have it move on. Try running the above code though if you haven't. As this one seems to keep pushing it regardless

Comment: Okay I'll give it a shot. Is there any way I can implement a timer in my original code that limits the amount of time the code spends at the readLine() command? For example, have it return null if it takes longer than 10 seconds maybe. This may be too much to ask for though!

Comment: Well, I know there is a thing such as WebDriverWait, and it is initialization is as follows: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, int secondsTimeout). You could something along the lines of say **wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(LearnMoreWay)));**

Answer (score 1):

This is not true.  BufferedReader.readLine() will not block if the underlying stream has reached the end of input.  It will return null.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine().

If your method is getting stuck there is another explanation.

Carefully check all of your exception handling and stream closing logic.

Comment: I know that. But I know for sure (by outputting stuff to the console at each step in the method) that while scraping through websites, the code gets hung at the readLine() command. It happens randomly, and sometimes when I rerun the code it parses the same website without any problem. Is there some way of knowing what the BufferedReader object contains when the code gets stuck?

Comment: You can use mark() and read() and reset() (check out the API) to see what it has already read.